# Finding an optimum solution that simultaneously satisfies multiple equations

Tags: matlab, optimization

I would like to find a single variable that optimizes the solution of two equations. For instance, `Target1=b*y1` and `Target2=b*y2`. I need to find a single `b` coefficient that simultaneously satisfies these equations.

How can I find the coefficient?

Comment: You can find a `b` that minimizes the mean square error in both equations. In general there wouldn't be a `b` that makes the error 0, because of measurement noise in the `y` and `Target` values. To minimize the mean square error, look for "least squares solution".

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I think I need to combine the two matrices into an equivalent one, such as Aeq*x=beq, and then use lsqlin function to obtain a least-square solution.

Answer (score 3):

this is called least square; the least square solution to

```
y1*b=target1
y2*b=target2
```

is

```
b=[y1;y2]\[target1;target2]
```

which is equivalently solving the pseudo-inversion of the above equation by

```
A=[y1;y2];
b=inv(A'*A)*A'*[target1;target2]
```